# javascript replace values if subtracting vs. adding

Tags: javascript

I am trying to optimize some code which will subtract or add values.  I'd like consolidate the following so that if the variable reduce = T then we use '-'and 'subtract' and if reduce = F then we use '+' and 'add'.  As you might notice we are using numeral.js and 'subtract' is its native subtract function.

Any suggestions would be great.

```
totalQty = numeral(licFldValue-(qty*liQty)).format('0');
totalQty = numeral(licFldValue+(qty*liQty)).format('0');

var updNewUsed = numeral(newCAlUsed).subtract(newDiff).format('0');
var updNewUsed = numeral(newCAlUsed).add(newDiff).format('0');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), `?`:

```
totalQty = reduce ? numeral(licFldValue-(qty*liQty)).format('0') : numeral(licFldValue+(qty*liQty)).format('0');

var updNewUsed = reduce ? numeral(newCAlUsed).subtract(newDiff).format('0') : numeral(newCAlUsed).add(newDiff).format('0');
```

The format is `condition ? exp1 : exp2`. If `condition` is `true`, return `exp1`, if `false`, return `exp2`.

Comment: That looks great, I'm going to give a it a try.  Thank you very much.